# Find out if validation errors exist in InfoPath form

Tags: infopath, validation, error-handling

Does anyone perhaps know of a way to find out at any point when a form is filled in if there are any validation errors on the page? I am having a lot of trouble with users that are not very knowledgeable with computers. The corporate branding of all sites and forms etc. where I work specifies that certain headings and such must be red and bolded. Now when a user fills in a form with any validation errors they get the message advising them to look out for the red marked asterisk and/or borders.

At this point the user gets confused and sees some red everywhere on the form, not knowing where to fix their error. The next step is, naturally, to phone me and complain that the form is broken.

[image]

What I want to do is perhaps have a formatting rule on the submit button to hide it if any validation rules exist on the page. I do not want to have a manual field that somehow becomes true specified by the rules when there is no more validation errors, because some of these rules can work out to have 50+ fields in them.

The next logical step would be to be able to message the user with some details on what needs to be fixed at the bottom of the form for the submit button to appear. These messages should naturally disappear dynamically as the fields are corrected.

I will settle for now, however, for a way to determine that there are no validation errors on a page. (without attempting to click submit and firing the automatic error message dialog that is..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carel,

You should add a Validation Summary kind of a View/Box where you put all the labels and apply Rules for them to show/hide!

Following screenshot will help you what I am trying to say: 
[image]

Or if the validations are complex and not be done by Rules, then you have to go for writing code: 
[Validation summary in InfoPath 2010](http://infopath.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/validation-summary-infopath-2010/)

Comment: Arsalan, this looks good and should theoretically work, however the issue I have with it is that I will have to format rules to hide 50 odd plus fields. This in itself is not a problem except that I'm lazy. Further, I guess I can then add a rule to hide the submit button if validationField1 == true OR validationField2 == true OR validationField3 == true ... etc. Doing this in a rule with 50+ OR's might get a bit dicey.
Thanks for the reply though